# How do I load only a part of jpg with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am looking for a way to load only a part of a jpg. I tried XMLHttpRequest but I could not figure it out.

```
    request.open("GET", "js.jpg", true);
    request.responseType = "blob";
```

This gets me an image and I can use it to display it. For example the image is 100kb big, I only want 50kb. Is this possible. I know that the image is cracked but I want to try something. Thank you

edit:

My goal is to load for example 50kb instead of the whole 100kb to save traffic I guess ;)

Comment: Have your server deliver 50 kb instead of 100kb. You can't control how much you receive on the client side. Also, saving traffic by breaking things isn't exactly the smartest move you can make.

Comment: rather then thinking at javascript you put logic at server side to provide 2 version of each images (hq and low quality)!!! you can decrease quality at serverside

Answer (score -3):

I did this by putting the image inside a div, and the div height = image height / 2.   of course, in my app the div height is a portion of the available screen height so that in different pc browser or mobile browser or Webview in native Android or iPhone, the display are similar.

Comment: How does that address the question which was how to download only part of the resource?

Comment: this wouldn't affect the size loaded from the server in bytes I guess

Comment: nope! you download the whole but display half!

Comment: "My goal is to load for example 50kb instead of the whole 100kb to save traffic"